# Saying a period of time of -ties (ex: the 80s to 90s) for a research paper correctly

Tags: numbers, time, academia, academic-writing

I'm trying to write a sentence that mentions a specific period of time, though I'm not sure if I wrote it correctly or not. Here's what I have.

We have succeeded in the era of the 1960s to 1980s

Things I'm unsure about:
the use of "to" between 1960s and 1980s, maybe I could replace it with "until" instead?
the way I write "1960s" or "1980s" maybe "1960s-1980s", "sixties to eighties", "60s to 80s" could be used instead?

Comment: I wonder about using "era" to describe such a period. There were many changes...

Comment: '60s to 80s' would IMO span *three* decades. A decade already is a time span, so it seems unusual to use them to refer to a greater time span, but [this link](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/culture-and-history-1960s-80s-disintegrating-chemistry-can-save-it-180957267/) uses your phrasing.

Comment: Would replacing "era" into something like just "the time period of" be better?